# I want to display 16 boxes within each box i want to display three images

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I want to display 16 boxes within each box i want to display three images.

For example:

```
<tr>
    <td style="width:auto; padding:15px;">
        <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" >
    </td>
    <td style="width:300px; padding:15px;">
        <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" >
    </td>
    <td style="width:300px; padding:15px;">
        <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" >
    </td>
    <td style="width:300px; padding:15px;">
        <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" >
    </td>
</tr>
```

So far i have a table of 4x4 above is only single row is shown.

Now how will i proceed in order to achieve this ..
will table is a good choice for this type of problem....

And i want this

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
       <td style="width:auto;">

            <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" height="50" width="50">    
        </td>

        <td style="width:auto;">
            <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" height="50" width="50">    
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"  style="width:auto;">

            <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" height="50" width="100">
        </td>
    </tr
```

But if i place this table within the main table its whole structure gets disoriented ...
i want this type of structure in 16 separate box...

Comment: Do you know css? You have not used it here or forgot to post here.

Comment: The big question is how are the three images going to be formatted inside each box?  What size are the 16 boxes you want to create?  Does it need to be responsive?

Comment: yes they need to be responsive.. pics are a place..i have places set of DIV tags inside <td> tag..Can you tell me how to remove the spacing between the DIV tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I ask why you are using a Tables instead of DIVs? 
But, just copy your img code and thats is how you display 3 images inside each box.

```
<tr>
    <td style="width:auto; padding:15px;">
        <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" >
        <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" >
        <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" >
    </td>
    <td style="width:300px; padding:15px;">
        <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" >
        <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" >
        <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" >
    </td>
    <td style="width:300px; padding:15px;">
        <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" >
        <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" >
        <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" >
    </td>
    <td style="width:300px; padding:15px;">
       <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" >
        <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" >
        <img src="/static/images/seo1.jpg" >
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: According to you images will be displaying opposite two each other...I have edited the my question please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Now who will create **16 boxes??**

If you know jQuery, it would have been simpler.

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

---

```
//As I always avoid using table's
for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
    $('#main').append('<div></div>');
    for(var j=0;j<4;j++){
        $('#main>div').eq(i).append('<div></div>');
    }
}
```

and then using css:

```
#main>div>div{float:left;/*some width and height values here*/}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ejoxoz/3/edit)**

Comment: Can every image can be changed dynamically...??

Comment: I created the complete elements dynamically. so, yes ofcourse.